# Maven, jersey, org.json - ClassNotFoundException despite import, dependency and classpath being correct

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jersey, org.json

I'm using intellij idea and Maven for this project - a glassfish-based REST webservice. I'm trying to execute the following method:

```
import org.json.*;


public void loadDestinations() throws Exception{

    InputStream is = InfoLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/destinations.json");
    String jsonTxt = is.toString();

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonTxt);
    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("destinations");
    //etc...
```

However, when the server starts, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
  Startup of context /aos_project_artifact_war failed due to previous errors]]

[2016-11-09T23:52:34.262+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-CORE-00108] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=42 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1478731954262] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5954)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
[2016-11-09T23:52:34.264+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=42 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1478731954264] [levelValue: 900] [[
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
```

I have scoured the web for this, and the answers seem to state one of the following:

1) add import (I have that, the code completion in intellij works fine too)

2) add depenedency to pom.xml (I have this as well, in the following form:)

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160810</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I even tried adding the `<scope>compile</scope>`, as referenced by one of the threads (so removing this would have no effect)

3) Making sure it is in my classpath. So, I went to intellij idea and ensured it is there:[image]

As you can see, the library is included.

What could be wrong here? Have I done any of the checks wrong? Could this point to a compatibility issue between org.json and glassfish/jersey? Or is it a problem with the IDE?

Comment: Have you already checked different versions from JSON? [Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) is the lists from the Maven Repository.

Comment: So the jar is in your project libraries. Is it in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your war file?

Comment: @Andreas, you are right. It is not included in the WEB-INF/lib folder. However, when I go to Project Structure->Project Settings->Artifacts->Output Layout in Intellij, the library is present in the WEB-INF/lib folder - so something is just making it not correctly get included in the output WAR when building. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Execute mvn dependnecy:tree on maven project of war. if its output contains org.json:json with scope compile, check maven-war-plugin configuration. May be it contains packagingExcludes in configuration.